# Root password while logging in as guest

Tags: root

I have installed Ubuntu using WUBI from my Windows OS. I created my username and its password. While I am trying to log in it's saying that the password is wrong. I have reinstalled 3 times giving the same problem.

How can I reset the root password in order for me to install an application?

Comment: Are you sure that the keyboard layout is the same for defining the password during installation and when logging in? This might save you some time and trouble.

Comment: am not sure if it changes

Answer (score -2):

I think you haven`t root password and you must created.

Type the following command:

`sudo passwd`
The following message will appear:

`[sudo] password for [username]: [Type your user password and press return]`

After that another message will appear, the following:

`Type new UNIX password: [Type the root password you want]`

Now the last thing you need to do, the following:

`Retype new UNIX password: [Retype the root password you chosen before]`

The following message will appear:

`passwd: password updated successfully`

Comment: I doubt that the guest will have a) a password b) be in the adm or sudo group.

Comment: thanx man, but am in the guest account am getting this error  sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permi

Comment: Setting a root password is definitely not necessary!

Comment: I agree; but would d you care to explain why? Otherwise, this comment is not really helpful (no offence meant)